# My enemy isn't moving when my character is standing still

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, pygame, game-physics

I'm currently coding a game on python, and I need a way for the enemy to run towards the player. It has to have a constant velocity of 5 pixels a cycle and this is my current code:

```
def move(self,character):
    characterposition = Vector(character.posx,character.posy)
    self.position = Vector(self.posx,self.posy)
    dist = characterposition.subtract(self.position)
    dist.normal(dist.length())
    length = dist.length()
    ratio = self.speed/math.sqrt(length)
    self.posx += dist.x * ratio
    self.posy += dist.y * ratio
```

this seems to be working until my character stops moving. When the character stops moving, the enemy stops as well. This is a problem and I would appreciate any suggestions.

Edit: Heres my loop.

```py
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             run = False
             continue
        updatecharacterposition()
        collided = checkforbarriercollision()
        badguy.move(character)
        if collided:
            print("YOU LOST")
            pygame.quit()
            time.sleep(5)
    redrawgamewindow()
```

Comment: Rabbid76, I have included the loop code, could you go through it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the indenting in the code above correct? It shows `updatecharacterposition()` and the lines after it inside the `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop.

If that is really the case, then none of that code will get called if you are not getting any events. That would cause all of the movement to stop.

Try this:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             run = False
             continue
    updatecharacterposition()
    collided = checkforbarriercollision()
    badguy.move(character)
    if collided:
        print("YOU LOST")
        pygame.quit()
        time.sleep(5)
    redrawgamewindow()
```

On a side note, it seems odd to me that `badguy.move(character)` is after the collision check. Usually you would move everything (the player and the 'badguy') and then do the collision check.

Comment: THANK YOU, I cant believe i made such a dumb mistake

Comment: @VigneshMuralidharan I added a comment at the end about the position of the collision check.

Comment: @VigneshMuralidharan As a way to help you debug these things yourself (if you do not have a debugger). you can try adding print statements. You would have discovered that code was not being reached when movement stopped and you likely would have figured it out.